# * Selector inside CSS Media Query does not affect all page elements

Tags: html, css

In the following code, i've set the body's margin to be 10px (all margins). What i did expect, is when we enter the resolution of less then 600px (the media query), then the * selector, which has margin:0px; => will affect all elements (including body) but it didn't happen and margin remains. why does the * selector doesn't affect all the elements in this code example?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:10px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #BDDFF9;
}
header {
    width:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  * {
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
  }

  body {
    background-color:#D2D2D2;
  }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    Text
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because `*` is the least specific CSS selector, and is overridden by every other selector. You must apply styles to individual selectors

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #BDDFF9;
}

header {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #D2D2D2;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  Text
</header>
```

The reason `*` didn't work is that there are rules attached to `body` and those are more specific than `*`. It is not a good idea to use `*` to override styles. Here is a good [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) article.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but can you please clarify the answer?. Obveisly, the easy thing to do is to set margin on the actual class (body in our case), but then... i still don't understand why the * selector failed to work here, and if there is a way it will work, or we can't use it at all?.